# netcat udp address already in use

Tags: networking, udp

I am trying get a response from the server by using the command `echo 'my message' | nc -l -u 127.0.0.1 2947`

But I get `nc:Address already in use.` for a response. How do find the reason for this message?

Answer (score 2):

A process is probably already listening on UDP port 2947.  You can get the PID of the process by running:

```
fuser -n udp 2947
```

Or browse the list of listening UDP ports to find your process:

```
netstat -plun
```

Comment: Thank you.Now I changed the port number and used nc command with new port number.Now it just hangs.It works with TCP and gives 'connection established' message.